# Derivate in Implicit function theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-derivative, implicit-function-theorem

I try to solve the exercise 0.1 given here
[https://webspace.science.uu.nl/~kolk0101/Books/Analysis/implicitapplic.pdf](https://webspace.science.uu.nl/%7Ekolk0101/Books/Analysis/implicitapplic.pdf).
I have issues proving part (ii) the last formula
$$D_2 \psi(0) = 1/g(0)$$
I will write $D_2 \psi(0)$ as $\partial_t \psi(t)$ since $t$ is the second variable and is one dimensional.

So by the implicit function theorem and choosing $x$ as the to be solved variable $x= \psi(y,t)$ it holds

$$\partial_{t}\psi(y,t) = -\partial_x F(\psi(y,t),y,t)^{-1}\partial_t F(\psi(y,t),y,t)$$
$$
\Rightarrow \partial_t \psi(0,0) = 
\underbrace{-g(0)^{-1}}_{-\partial_x F(\psi(y,t),y,t)^{-1} |y=t=0}\partial_t(\psi(0,t)g(\psi(0,t))-t) = ... $$

Where we used

$f(x,0) = xg(x)$ and $F(x,y,t) = f(x,y) -t $
$$... = -g(0)^{-1} (\partial_t \psi(0,0)g(\psi(0,0)) + \underbrace{\psi(0,0)}_{=0} g'(\psi(0,0))\partial_t \psi(0,0) -1 ) = -g(0)^{-1} (\partial_t\psi(0,0)g(0)-1)$$
where we used $\psi(0,0) = 0$
Hence
$$\partial_t \psi (0,0) = -g(0)^{-1} (\partial_t \psi(0,0) g(0) -1) = -\partial_t\psi(0,0) + \frac{1}{g(0)} \Leftrightarrow \partial_t \psi(0,0) = \frac{1}{2g(0)}$$
which is not the desired formula.
Does anyone spot the problem ?

Thank you so much

Comment: Not directly related to your question: I think there is a misprint in that sheet, both at the end of the exercise and at the end of the solution: they wrote $D_1f$ instead of $D_2f.$

Comment: Please take the effort to type the question here. Who knows how long that link will be viable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your interpretation of $\partial_t F(\psi(y,t),y,t).$ You must not differentiate (w.r.t. $t$) $(y,t)\mapsto F(\psi(y,t),y,t)$ at the point $(y,t)$ but $(x,y,t)\mapsto F(x,y,t)$ (i.e. $F$) at the point $(\psi(y,t),y,t).$

Why so? to avoid such an ambiguity, let us denote by $D_1F,D_2F,D_3F$ the differentials of $F(x,y,t)$ w.r.t. $x,y,t.$ Differentiating the equation
$$F(\psi(y,t),y,t)=0$$
w.r.t. $t$ gives:
$$D_1F(\psi(y,t),y,t)\partial_t\psi(y,t)+D_3F(\psi(y,t),y,t)=0,$$
hence
$$D_1F(0)\partial_t\psi(0)+D_3F(0)=0,$$
i.e.
$$g(0)\partial_t\psi(0)-1=0.$$